# Algorithm that merges two $n$ sorted lists require $2n-1$ comparisons

Tags: algorithms, sorting

How can I write an adversary argument to prove that to prove that any comparison-based algorithm that merges two n-element sorted lists into a single sorted list requires at least $2n-1$ comparisons in its worst-case run?

Comment: Perhaps you will gain some insight by thinking about what case would minimize the number of comparisons?

Comment: It's easy to imagine two arrays. Suppose you going to compare two arrays and you stay in first position $a[0]$ you need to compare $a[0]$ with $n/2$ elements from second array, after this you should take as base element $b[n/2]$ and compare it with $n/2$ elements from first array. So we will get : $n/2 + n/2 + n/4 + n/4 + \dots - 1$ this actually what you want.

Comment: $n=4$ : {5 6 8 10} {2 3 7 9}

Comment: @openspsce:  I think the Question is not about how to achieve worst case $2n-1$ comparisons, but rather about why this is a required number of comparisons in the worst case for *any* sorted merge algorithm.